# How to validate $set 'keys' with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a rather specific case: Using mongoose/mongo and user objects

I want to find and update user in one call.

```
 DB.collection('users').findOneAndUpdate({localId: id} ,{ "$set": { "name": "lla", "usnme": "As"} } ,callback);
```

Note that 'username' is spelled wrong. Yet mongo updated the first field(name) and does not give any error about the second.

How can I validate the keys I pass in $set without making more than one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What MongoDB suggests here is called [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/):

In your specific case you could run the following command to make sure that no additional ("incorrect") fields can be added by anyone:

```
db.runCommand({ "collMod": "users", "validator": {
  $jsonSchema: {
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      "_id": {
         bsonType: "objectId"
      },
      "name": {
         bsonType: "string"
      },
      "username": {
        bsonType: "string"
      }
    }
  }
}})
```

Beyond that I cannot really think of any solution since MongoDB is a document database which by default is schemaless and hence won't stop you from creating the fields you tell it to create...